# Licensing for yoga drawings from a book?

Tags: images, copyright, licensing

What type of permission is needed to use yoga drawings from a book I own and one I do not? I am writing an ebook and would like to reuse some of the drawings. I will give the book author credit in my book.

Answer (score 10):

Whether or not you own the book is irrelevant. Purchasing a book does not give you any rights to reproduce any part of it.

You can’t use the images (or text) from the book without express prior written permission. This would need to be requested from whoever owns the copyright. This will be stated somewhere in the book. Giving credit is not enough. If permission is given (which is far from guaranteed) then they will probably want paying.

I would advise creating your own illustrations or finding someone who can create them for you. Alternatively, you could get someone to photograph you or a friend in the required yoga stances.